# Wordpress theme works on localhost but fails on ec2 with jquery error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, typeerror

I have created a woocommerce wordpress store with one of the popular themes.
It works fine on localhost on my mac. I created a new ec2 instance(AMI) and migrated my site to it. I have followed all instructions to properly migrate the site.(DB changes, folder permissions etc.)

When I open the site my theme is not applied. It just looks all broken.
When I checked in developer tool in chrome/safari i get below error in the javascript console.

```js
[Error] TypeError: a(document).on is not a function. (In 'a(document).on', 'a(document).on' is undefined)
 (anonymous function) (add-to-cart.min.js:4:89)
 resolveWith (jquery.min.js:16:14217)
 ready (jquery.min.js:16:9208)
 y (jquery.min.js:16:13685)
```

Further debugging and comparing the viewsource of server vs localhost, it seems that few jquery scripts are not emitted in html from server but they are present in localhost.
Few missing scripts in server html are:

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8888/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>

...
...

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($){
   $('#main-slider .bx-slider').slick({
    dots: true,
    arrows: false,
    speed: 1000,
    fade: false,
    cssEase: 'linear',
    autoplaySpeed:7000,
    autoplay:true,
    adaptiveHeight:true,
    infinite:true,
                draggable: true,
   });

        
  });
 </script>
```

Another jquery section missing under 

        
, but is present on localhost is:

```js
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#ticker').ticker({
              speed: 0.10,           // The speed of the reveal
              ajaxFeed: false,       // Populate jQuery News Ticker via a feed
              feedUrl: false,        // The URL of the feed
           // MUST BE ON THE SAME DOMAIN AS THE TICKER
              //feedType: 'xml',       // Currently only XML
              htmlFeed: true,        // Populate jQuery News Ticker via HTML
              debugMode: true,       // Show some helpful errors in the console or as alerts
             // SHOULD BE SET TO FALSE FOR PRODUCTION SITES!
              controls: true,        // Whether or not to show the jQuery News Ticker controls
              titleText: 'Latest News',   // To remove the title set this to an empty String
              displayType: 'reveal', // Animation type - current options are 'reveal' or 'fade'
              direction: 'ltr',       // Ticker direction - current options are 'ltr' or 'rtl'
              fadeInSpeed: 900,      // Speed of fade in animation
              fadeOutSpeed: 300,   
              pauseOnItems: 3000,    // The pause on a news item before being replaced  
          });
});
</script>
```

Can someone please help in understanding what could be the possible cause of this behaviour of missing jQuery scripts.

Note: The wp-includes/js in ec2 instance contains all the files present in localhost.

Comment: Have you considered to fix the typo (`a(document).on`) in `add-to-cart.min.js`? It should probably read `$(document).on` or `jQuery(document).on`.

Comment: Have u modified ur permalinks from the wp-admin setting. Also update your site url from localhost to live domain in the setting page.

Comment: These are the inbuilt script from woocommerce.  add-to-cart.min.js

Comment: Yes, as told i have done all the changes related to links. Basically, i took the backup of local mysql scripts dump and replaced localhost with IP of ec2 instance.

Comment: ok, looks like i was able to get around that jquery error: When initially site was not working, i added custom logic in functions.php to enqueue jquery from google cdn , due to which jquery version was conflicting. Now it is looking better in console, although the site is still not fully functional. Its URLs to cart, product etc are all broken.

Comment: ok, the broken links is resolved now by 2 steps. First, i copied the .htaccess from local to server. so it had different folder in server, so i need to modify that. Second, for htaccess of the folder to be affective have to override setting in httpd.conf as per this link https://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalink-error-url-not-found-on-server

Comment: 1 more observation and may be the last puzzle to solve, all changes done under customizer locally are gone when moved to server. Any thoughts why that could happen.